# Windows Phone 7.1 Local Database sample

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I download a sample from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-71-Local-da2fdf80/view/Discussions, and then import to Visual Studio and run in the WP7 Emulator. When I would like to add the new task i have got a exception: *Set property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker.ItemCountThreshold' threw an exception. [Line: 42 Position: 63]*

Could someone resolve this problem?

Comment: What exception was thrown? More details are necessary.

Comment: @Bernard You could download, compile and run this sample (therefore i paste link to project). If you want to look at exception here it is: http://pastebin.com/Rri8Qd3k

Comment: Object in application. Its a simple TODO application. When you run this app you click on the "Task" button and then on the appbar add new task. Then exception was thrown. The problem is with the ListPicker, but I am new int wp7 development and I don't know what exactly is wrong;/

Comment: I had no problems to add task. What vs are you using?

Comment: Really? Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. So what's can be wrong?